# DBeaver connection to Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-synapse, dbeaver

I would like to query data from Azure Synapse Analytics with DBeaver.

- I am using the community version of DBeaver
- On the machine which I am running DBeaver, I have installed the MS SQL Server ODBC driver
- I have created the connection to Azure Synapse Analytics and it is successfully connecting to the server/instance
- On the 'Database Navigator', when I do a drop down list on my connection, I see the different SQL Pools/Databases that I have created.
- When I do a drop down on each database, I only see the schemas 'dbo', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' and 'sys'. But I do not see the schemas that I have created.
- When I do a drop down on each schema, I see tables, views, indexes, procedures, data types. When I do a drop down on 'tables' or 'views', I do not see anything.

Has someone tried querying data from Synapse Analytics with DBeaver ?

Has someone also experienced the same, not able to see all the schemas or to read any tables ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: No haven't tried it, but why not interact with Synapse via Synapse Studio (via the browser), SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS v18.x), and Azure Data Studio (ADS) which will work with Synapse?

Comment: We are using DBeaver for connecting and querying with Databricks. The idea was to use the same for Databricks and Synapse :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to choose to connect to 'Azure SQL Server':

[image: Select 'Azure SQL Server']

Then, on the next screen, all you need to do is fill in the `Host`, `Username`, and `Password`. The `Host` is the value you get from your Synapse Workspace for the `Serverless SQL endpoint`.

Like this:

[image: Enter access details]

Then it should connect successfully.